# Creating a new column based on value of existing column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, series

I would like  to create a new column (I.e. Winning_Time) as shown below table. All the Time_diff at Match_state ( Winning) will be stored in the new column **Winning_Time**. The rest rows will be filled with NaN or zero.
How can I do that?

```
gsm_id  Goal_Flag   Union_Level Team_SR Match_state   Time_diff           Wining_Time
2462796 First goal  Scored      Burnley  Winning    0 days 00:23:15.00   0 days 00:23:15.00
2462796 First goal  Conceded    Chelsea  Losing     0 days 00:23:15.00   NaN               
2462796 Other goals Scored      Burnley  Winning    0 days 00:15:20.00   0 days 00:15:20.00
2462796 Other goals Conceded    Chelsea  Losing     0 days 00:15:20.00   NaN
2462796 Other goals Scored      Burnley  Winning    0 days 00:03:34.00   0 days 00:03:34.00
2462796 Other goals Conceded    Chelsea  Losing     0 days 00:03:34.00   NaN
2462796 Other goals Scored      Chelsea  Losing     0 days 00:25:59.00   NaN
2462796 Other goals Conceded    Burnley  Winning    0 days 00:25:59.00   0 days 25:59.00
2462796 Last goal   Scored      Chelsea  Losing     0 days 00:19:11.00   NaN
2462796 Last goal   Conceded    Burnley  Winning    0 days 00:19:11.00   0 days 00:19:11.00
2462795 First goal  Scored      City     Winning    0 days 01:09:15.00   0 days 01:09:15.00 
2462795 First goal  Conceded    Brighton Losing     0 days 01:09:15.00   NaN
2462795 Last goal   Scored      City     Winning    0 days 00:05:21.00   0 days 00:05:21.00
2462795 Last goal   Conceded    Brighton Losing     0 days 00:05:21.00   NaN
```

Your advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Winning_Time'] = np.where(df['Match_state'] == 'Winning', df['Time_diff'], np.nan)
```

Here, `numpy.where` acts like a vectorised if / else statement.

Comment: i just happened to find out.
Anyway. Thanks a lot @jpp